# SVG Zoom and Pan

Tags: svg

I have an SVG layout (from D3) of a tree. I have an SVG element in my HTML that takes up 100% of the width and height of the page. Then, within that SVG element, D3 renders a group element with a bunch of circles and lines in it. For example:

```
<svg style='width:100%;height:100%;'>
    <g>
        ...stuff...
    </g>
</svg>
```

I want to be able to zoom and pan so that a certain portion of the tree (group element) takes up the screen. I have the exact coordinates of the area I want to zoom in on, so ideally, I want to move the SVG element X pixels up and to the left, then scale the whole element by Y. How can I best do that?

From what I'm reading, the viewBox attribute is best for this, but I just can't figure out how I would be able to zoom in on just one portion. [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg589508%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) example seems to get at what I want, but my SVG element is measured in percentages, not pixels. And even though the coordinate system is supposed to be arbitrary, I'm having a hard time converting between the two.

Comment: Did you try googling "svg zoom pan"?

Answer (score 1):

Here, I use this to zoom into certain regions of the SVG image. Change cx to the x coordinate, cy to the y coordinate, width and height are your call. The line you should be interested in is the `svgDocument.setAttribute(...)`

```
    function zoomTarget1() {
        var svgDocument = document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];
        var cx = 20;
        var cy = 20;
        var width = 610;
        svgDocument.setAttribute("viewBox", cx+" "+cy+" "+width+" 590");
        var reShow = svgDocument.getElementById("FloorSelection");
        showReturnButton(cx,cy, width, reShow);
    }
```